# Where is Fock on Klein-Gordon equation?

Tags: physics, terminology

I was researching a bit about the history of the famous Klein-Gordon equation and I found out that Fock also independently discovered it in the same year as Klein and Gordon, 1926. However, chronologically, the original articles where the equation appears are ordered with [Klein](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01397481)'s first (April 28, 1926), followed by [Fock](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01321989)'s (July 30, 1926), and [Gordon](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390840)'s last (September 29, 1926). However, I have seen at most three articles using the nomenclature "Klein-Fock-Gordon equation," while the widespread usage seems to be "Klein-Gordon equation." Is there any reason behind leaving Fock's name out of the equation?

Comment: This is a very usual kind of question, the answer is just: [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy)

Comment: Fock is not the only one not mentioned, see [Kragh](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/52/11/1024/1038484/Equation-with-the-many-fathers-The-Klein-Gordon). The equation was derived before Klein by Schrödinger and de Broglie, and independently by several others. Klein was the first to publish. Gordon was late to the party, but Schrödinger acquiesced to a "*very convenient distinction*" (with his equation), adding "*I would rather not see it under
the name of de Broglie*". He was upset about his momentum as the derivative prescription being called "de Broglie's" at the time.

Comment: Western Literature: Klein-Gordon or KG equation. Eastern (Soviet plus former communist countries in Eastern and Central Europe): Klein-Gordon-Fock equation.